# The chrome-extension code is not running as extension but working as different web page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have written the following code to create a chrome extension for showing contests on codechef site. [www.codechef.com/contests](http://www.codechef.com/contests)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fetchPage(url) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        error: function(request, status) {
            alert('Error fetching ' + url);
        },
        success: function(data) {

            var textstring = "";
            var $divelem = $("div.table-questions",$(data));
            var $headers = $("h3",$(data));
            var contsite = $divelem.size();
            for(i = 0;i < contsite;i++)
            {
                var ob = $divelem.eq(i);
                var tr = $('tr',ob);
                var trsize = tr.size();
                textstring += "<b>"+$headers.eq(i).html()+"</b><br>";
                for(j = 1;j < Math.min(10,trsize);j++)
                {
                    var td = $('td',tr[j]);
                    var tdsize = td.size();
                    for(k = 0;k < tdsize;k++)
                    {
                        textstring += "\t"+td.eq(k).html()
                    }
                    textstring += "<br>";
                }

            }

            var element = document.createElement("div");
            element.innerHTML = textstring; 
            document.body.appendChild(element);
        }
    });

}

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() 
    {
        fetchPage("http://www.codechef.com/contests");
    });

</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

I have run the code on browser as a web page. It was working fine but when run as an extension, it was not showing anything. I could not find anything on net which solves this problem. The manifest.json file is as follows:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Codechef Plugin",
  "description": "This extension demonstrates a codechef event.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "main.html"
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use any inline code in the popup, move it all to an external file instead. You also need to request host permissions for the site you are trying to `$.get` from.

Comment: Thanks, that was a part of it. Even google api jquery link was not working. Dunno why. I download jquery script then added that.